# automate the edge update using selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

Is there anyway to update the new edge browser using selenium web driver? Can we do it by setting any option or capabilities?

My present code:

```
EdgeOptions op= new EdgeOptions();
            op.UseChromium = true;
            op.BinaryLocation = @"msedge.exe";
            
            var msedgedriverDir = @"webdriver location";
            var driver = new EdgeDriver(msedgedriverDir, op);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("my site");
```

I try to search online and on this site for a solution but did not get any working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the [Selenium web driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium?tabs=c-sharp) to automate the websites. We cannot access the update related settings of the Edge browser using the selenium web driver. So we cannot update the Edge browser by using the selenium web driver.

If you want to control the Edge updates for many users then you can try to deploy the Edge browser using [Configuration Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/apps/deploy-use/deploy-edge#configuration-manager-version-2002-and-later) and try to [manage updates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/apps/deploy-use/deploy-edge#update-microsoft-edge) by using it.

For a single user, by default Edge will download and install the updates automatically. You can control the updates using group policy.